# I can't run a dependency check using dependency-check-maven version 7.1.2. Getting Existing update in progress; waiting for update to complete

Tags: maven-dependency-check-plugin

I can't run the dependency check.
I have waiting a long time.  I have these messages:

I have an [INFO} message Lock file found [INFO] Lock file found `C:\Users\linda\.m2\repository\org\owasp\dependency-check-utils\7.1.2\..\..\dependency-check-data\7.0\odc.update.lock` [INFO] Existing update in progress;

[INFO] --- dependency-check-maven:7.1.2:check (default-cli) @ Module2.2 ---
[INFO] Lock file found `C:\Users\linda\.m2\repository\org\owasp\dependency-check-utils\7.1.2\..\..\dependency-check-data\7.0\odc.update.lock`
[INFO] Existing update in progress; waiting for update to complete

Here are the related lines from pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this, you need to change the maven build name to the project name. Then re-run the build and you should be good to go!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).